# Adding \begin{lstlisting} to a shorter command

Tags: listings, code, python

I have a project where I'm going to be making a great deal of code blocks. I've used styling with the listing module to set it up like so:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
def function_name(test1):
   # Does this work?
   """
   What about this
   """
   for x in range(10):
       print(x)
\end{lstlisting}
```

I'd like to be able to just do something along the lines of:

```
\begin{python}
yada yada yada
\end{python}
```

I've done some reading, and it sounds like there isn't a way to make the listing environment work inside a macro. Am I understanding that correctly? Is there a workaround? Most of the posts about this seemed somewhat contradictory to me - and I wasn't able to wrap my head around whether this is in fact possible. Thanks!

Comment: See the listings manual, it has measures to define your own listings like envs.

Comment: In more detail, `\lstdefinestyle{python}{....}`